# Want to close the menu whenever i click on any part of the webpage

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

The menu opens on the click of toggle button, i want the menu closed if i click on any part of the webpage

```
$('.category-toggle button').on('click',function(){
        $('.category-toggle').toggleClass('active');
      });

      var $CategoryTtoggle = $('.category-toggle');

      $CategoryTtoggle.each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);

        $this.on('clickoutside touchendoutside', function () {
          if ($this.hasClass('active')) { $this.removeClass('active'); }
        });
      });
```

Comment: can you add your js(jquery) code for menu open part, so we will be able to help you

Comment: Should the menu close even if you click the menu itself? Or only if you click any other part of the webpage?

Comment: just any part of the webpage, not on the whole menu div

Comment: Got it. Still need to see your relevant code to help though.

Comment: i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

You can trap click event on document and remove the active class if it's clicked outside of your menu container.

```
$('.category-toggle button').on('click',function(){
    $('.category-toggle').toggleClass('active');
});

jQuery(document).on('click', function(e){
    var $CategoryTtoggle = $('.category-toggle');
    if (!$CategoryTtoggle.is(e.target) && $CategoryTtoggle.has(e.target).length === 0 )
    {
        $CategoryTtoggle.removeClass('active'); 
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this. It only removes class `.active` if the click event does not originate from `.category-toggle` or a child of `.category-toggle`.

```
$('.category-toggle button').on('click',function(){
    $('.category-toggle').toggleClass('active');
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).closest(".category-toggle").length) {
        $(".category-toggle").removeClass("active")
    }  
})
```

Here's a working fiddle that models the effect: https://jsfiddle.net/qeaxu9c9/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can detect the click outside the menu by using event handler.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".category-toggle button").click(function(event) {
          event.stopPropagation(); //prevents event bubbling for parent elements
            $(".category-toggle .active").removeClass("active"); //to make sure that only one menu is opened at a time
            $(this).find(".category-toggle").toggleClass("active");
        });

       //To detect mouse click outside the menu bar     
       $("html").click(function() {
            $(".category-toggle").removeClass("active"); 
        });
    });
```